# XPages search returning undefined viewEntry

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a custom control which contains a view which be searched by passing in a value in the ?search parameter.  In most cases everything works as expected.  However, some results contain a single **undefined** viewEntry.  This always appears as the last entry on the first page regardless of the number of results returned.  The same search in the Notes client doesn't show any empty documents, nor are there any conflicts in the database.

I've managed to work around the error by checking for **typeof viewEntry == undefined** but would like to get to the bottom of why this is happening.

Comment: Does the view contain totals row?

Comment: Frantisek - No, it does not contain totals.  And it only occurs for certain search terms.

Comment: Does this happen for this one view only, or for several views? Have you rebuilt the view indices? (`load updall yourdb.nsf -R`) Or fixup? Can you create 1) a replica or 2) a new copy to another server and try there?

Comment: One more thing: Does this vary per search term? If you are searching by field value, does the field exist in all the documents and has the database ever contained documents with that field having different datatype? E.g. a NUMBER field that has contained TEXT values in the past?

Comment: Lauri - the search is simply a full-text search.  It does vary on the search term used. People are typically just entering a name and it only happens on a few names entered.  None of the names entered are key works or field names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the view's `AutoUpdate` property to `false` before doing your search? If not, please try that.

Comment: Lauri - I'm using a view data source on a viewPanel so AutoUpdate is not an option.  Unless you are talking about the update property in the actual view design element?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have response/conflicts documents that are not displayed in view. You can uncheck the Show Response Documents In Hierarchy and check the results.